# Why an output of attention decoder need to be combined with attention

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model

[legacy_seq2seq in tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L694)

```
x = linear([inp] + attns, input_size, True)
# Run the RNN.
cell_output, state = cell(x, state)
# Run the attention mechanism.
if i == 0 and initial_state_attention:
  with variable_scope.variable_scope(variable_scope.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
    attns = attention(state)
else:
  attns = attention(state)
with variable_scope.variable_scope("AttnOutputProjection"):
  output = linear([cell_output] + attns, output_size, True)
```

My question is that why we need to combine the cell_output with the attns rather than just use the cell_output as the output?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

attention mechanism required to put more attention on some special or specific node.

here you cell_output is a matrix in mathematics. and a representation or combination of nodes in deep learning.

so at the end , if you want to give more priorities to some data then you have to make some changes to your cell_output. and that's we are doing by doing some concatenation or addition or dot product operation to original matrix (cell_output).

```
let x = 5
and you want to make x = 7
then you can do x = x + 2(one way).
so that means you have make changes to your x variable. 
same operation you are doing to apply attention to your hidden layers nodes or in your case cell_output. 
here x is cell_output and 2 is attention output.
```

if you don't make any changes to your cell_output, then how come you will add attention to your output representation !!.

you can pass directly cell_output to final layer without combining with attention matrix or without applying attention. but then you need to know why attention mechanism required in Neural Network !!

Comment: I guess you misunderstand my problem...attention mechanism is functioned on the encoder hidden states (outputs), in decoder, it is used to decide which part of encoder hidden states is more important at current time. You can see that, attns is combined with decoder inputs at every time stamp, that's the way attention play a role. But the problem is why he also combines the outputs with attns.

Comment: yaah you are right. i completely agree with you. but attention means filtering more specific data correct me if i am wrong !!. so you can apply it at any stage of NN except before calculating objective function. so i think he is not doing any thing wrong.

Comment: the key point is that as we have already use attention combined with inputs to our decoder, that's means our decoder could take the information of all the encoder states but why we use it in outputs again. It's quite strange to use the attns twice right? Let's refer to the attention mechanism source paper by Bahdanau(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf), you can see that all the attention is used as input in decoder but never functioned on outputs. That's my problem.

Comment: i think you need to read doc statement of "attention_decoder" from legacy_seq2seq in tensorflow. specifically line number 580-594.

Comment: it just say then we calculate the output: output = linear(cell_output, new_attn). but no any explanation on why we need to do that. is there any paper follow the idea of that?

Comment: OK maybe I find the point. I may make mistake on cell_output and the real output. The real output seems to be constructed by the cell output. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you were right from beginning that one attention is enough for all perceptron . my point was that here cell_output is not the last output. and why can't we apply multiple attention ? I think we can but again it depends on use case and architecture!! thanks man.